# Cortar cadena con split() java

Tags: java

Alguno sabe cómo podría partir una cadena como esta donde deba meter todas las cadenas identificadas por coma, pero pasa que la última cadena no debe llevar coma, ósea cadena3.

Y en una pregunta vieja de stack vi que le decían a alguien que se podía forzar al método split para que metiera otra cadena, mi idea seria como decirle que me meta todas las cadenas + 1 porque la ultima no tiene coma, pero no sé como podría decírselo.

Otra duda es que si no saben cómo podría usar el Split para meter al vector toda esta cadena así **`:REAL;`**, con los dos puntos y el punto y coma al final.

No sé como podría indicarle eso al *split*, gracias por la ayuda.

> cadena1, cadena2,cadena3 :REAL;

```
String[] parts = lineaSinEspacios.split(",", + 1);
System.out.println(parts[3]);
```

Al final el array que espero recibir es este:

> **[ cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 :REAL; ]**

Lo que pasa es que mi código se basa en crear un compilador, entonces este compilador hace el análisis de que las variables estén correctamente escritas entonces, por ejemplo:

> **variable1, variable2, variable3, variable5 :REAL;**
>
> **numero1, numero2 : CHAR;**

Si se dan cuenta estos son dos ejemplos correctos, la última variable no termina con **`,`** sino con **`:`**.

Pero la última variable no necesariamente debe llevar espacio podría verse de esta forma, y esta bien.

> **cadena1,cadena2,cadena3:REAL;**

Lo que pasa es que la ultima variable lo que tiene al a derecha es **`:`**.

El arreglo final podría quedar de esta forma:

> **[cadena1,cadena2,cadena3:REAL;]**

Necesito dividir las cadenas por **`, :  ;`** pero no sé como meter todo eso en un *split*.

Comment: No me queda del todo claro si querés separar por comas y saltos de línea (ambos) o espacios, o si siempre la última parte va entre dos puntos y punto y coma... Se puede interpretar de formas diferentes. ¿Podrás [edit] la pregunta agregando algunos ejemplos más y el resultado esperado?

Comment: Pero la última coma no es necesaria `String lineaSinEspacios = "cadena1,cadena2,cadena3";
         String[] parts = lineaSinEspacios.split(",");``retornará 3 elementos

Comment: Hola Esther, el array  que esperas recibir es este?: ***[ cadena1, cadena2, cadena3, :REAL ]***?, si no lo es, podrías mostrarnos que esperas?

Comment: @MarcePuente el array que espero recibir es este [ cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 :REAL; ]

Comment: Me refiero al que esperas generar.

Comment: si por eso el array que espero generar es este [ cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 :REAL; ]

Comment: lo que pasa es que mi programa se basa en crear un compilador de un lenguaje ochentero

Comment: entonces necesito evaluar si las definiciones de variables son correctas

Comment: entonces se define

variable, variable : TIPO DE DATO;

Comment: por eso es que la cadena3 no tiene , porque lo que tiene es : ya que luego sigue el tipo de dato

Comment: @Pollo listo nose si lo aprecias mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver intentare responder a riesgo de que me caigan negativos ya que tu pregunta no esta clara del todo.

Como bien sabes el método [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) según la documentación tiene como parámetros **`split(String regex, int limit)`** que en este caso me parece que solo necesitas utilizar el regex.

Según tu pregunta quieres partir la cadena no solo por **`,`** si no también por **`:`** *desconozco el porqué de esto o el funcionamiento que tendrá posteriormente* pero te explicaré lo que sucederá y es posible que estés consiente de esto.

Primero para partir una cadena con más de un caracter debes usar expresiones regulares, en este caso si quisieras partir por ejemplo por **`,`** y **`:`** utilizarías `[,:]` que en JAVA seria de la siguiente forma:

```
String variables = "cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 :REAL;";
String arr[] = variables.split("[,:]");
```

La salida seria la siguiente:

> **[cadena1, cadena2, cadena3, REAL;]**

Que obviamente seria un array de tamaño 4, ahora debes tener claro que cuando utilizas un caracter en el *split* *"este desaparece de la cadena"* por lo mismo si partes por **`:`** o por **`;`** estos no aparecerán de la forma que esperas en la ultima posición como muestras en tu ejemplo **`:REAL;`**.

Ahora si quieres que te muestre como en tu ejemplo y citó el ejemplo de salida que muestras:

> **[cadena1, cadena2, cadena3:REAL;]**

Para hacer eso bastaría con hacer:

```
String variables = "cadena1, cadena2, cadena3 :REAL;";
String arr[] = variables.split(",");
```

Obviamente el tamaño del array seria de 3 y no así de cuatro como el anterior ejemplo.

En este caso sin expresiones regulares y tendrías esa salida que muestras, ahora tienes que tener en mente que el separador del array por defecto siempre es **`,`** y no puedes usar un separador como un **`:`** o un **`;`**, esto lo digo porque posiblemente entendí que querías que también estos caracteres actúen como separadores, pues eso no pasará jeje.

Espero haberte ayudado de alguna forma siempre puedes dejarme un comentario si tienes alguna duda. ;)

Comment: Lo ideal es preguntar al OP sobre su pregunta y ayudarle a formularla correctamente antes de responder, tal vez lo que respondas no es lo que desea.

Comment: no no realmente si me ayudaste jejeje, esas dos formas que funcionan para intentar resolver mi codigo

Comment: muchas gracias bien

Comment: @Jorgesys, si efectivamente soy consiente de ello, lo que sucede es que vi los comentarios donde ya le habían preguntado a OP y era un poco complicado, posiblemente lo mejor habría sido crear una sala de chat.